# Plotting Shapely Linestring and shapely geo Point Coordinate on same Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I have two GeoDataFrames.  One which is a street map of a City, and the other are coordinates of the NHTSA Crash Data.

I'm having trouble figuring out a method to convert from the LineString Type, which is the StreetMap to the Point Type, which is a geocoordinate.

Ultimately Matplot's scale is just way off, which plots things completely wrong.

So what am I missing to plot these things.  Here are some sample Data Frames.

```
                         geometry  
72     POINT (-88.73746 40.72734)  
4093   POINT (-88.95345 40.53861)  
7638   POINT (-88.99324 40.47142)
```

And the other dataframe

```
0        LINESTRING (903617.335 1487219.494, 903780.564...
1        LINESTRING (913845.303 1489995.746, 914731.553...
2        LINESTRING (909998.735 1489953.767, 911530.535...
```

I've looked at the shapely documentation, but being new to Geo work, I could use a boost.

**UPDATE PLOT CODE**. 
I thought i would also update my plot code, maybe I need to do something with the scale?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
street_map.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.4, color='grey')
geo_df[geo_df['work_zone']=='None'].plot(ax=ax,
                                         markersize=20,
                                         color = 'orange',
                                         marker='o',
                                         label='None')
geo_df[geo_df['work_zone']=='Maintenance'].plot(ax=ax,
                                                markersize=20,
                                                color = 'red',
                                                marker='^',
                                                label='Maintenance')
plt.legend(prop={'size': 15});
```

Comment: You need to have both in the same CRS. Use something like `gdf1.to_crs(gdf2)`.

Comment: Well, I did try that.  Doesn't seem to have any impact on the scale of the matplot.  
` geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=street_map.crs, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude, df.latitude)). 
`

Comment: So when i explicitly set the EPSG `"EPSG:4326"` I do see the plot scale change to the boundries of the GPS coordinates.  It still renders the Linestrings way off the scale though.  So something else is up as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed CRS, so one of your data frames needs to be reprojected to match the other. As you LineString gdf is projected, I would use that CRS.

```
geo_df = geo_df.to_crs(street_map.crs) # thin line does the trick

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
street_map.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.4, color='grey')
geo_df[geo_df['work_zone']=='None'].plot(ax=ax,
                                         markersize=20,
                                         color = 'orange',
                                         marker='o',
                                         label='None')
geo_df[geo_df['work_zone']=='Maintenance'].plot(ax=ax,
                                                markersize=20,
                                                color = 'red',
                                                marker='^',
                                                label='Maintenance')
plt.legend(prop={'size': 15});
```

Comment: That worked Thanks! @martinfleis
After that line my points look like this...
`72       POINT (872242.960 1479138.653)`